# Service name is missing Consul

Tags: .net, consul

I am trying to add service to consul through configuration file.

While doing so, I am getting the following error.

Error Message:-

```
==> Starting Consul agent...
==> Error starting agent: failed adding service "12WCF": Service name missing
```

Code Used:

```
{
"service": {
    "name": "WCF",  
    "id" : "12WCF",
    "address" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 62133        
}
}
```

Command:-
`consul.exe agent --dev`

I am using Windows for development.

I have provided the service name in the config. But still it is says as, service name is missing.

Am I missing any other thing.

Could any one provide some suggestions on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah,

Got it. So, we have to add an attrib named "service" to the json which solves the problem.

So, the final config will look like,

```
{
"service": {
"id":"somename",
"name":"nameofthissevice",
"service": "myservice",
"address": "127.0.0.1",
"port": 62133
}
}
```

Do not know why consul did not mention this in their docs.

Thx.